How can I solve property decorator
@State giving error. error is here. how can I solve this error. I am using typescript 5.4.5 version.
I am using vite-web project. this file in src directory. if you try typescript playgorund no problem. but my vite project giving error
Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
  The runtime will invoke the decorator with 3 arguments, but the decorator expects 2.ts(1240)
Decorator function return type is 'ClassAccessorDecoratorResult<unknown, unknown>' but is expected to be 'void' or 'any'.ts(1271)

function State<This, Return>(
  target: ClassAccessorDecoratorTarget<This, Return>,
  _context: ClassAccessorDecoratorContext<This, Return>
) {
  const result: ClassAccessorDecoratorResult<This, Return> = {
    get(this: This) {
      return target.get.call(this);
    },
    set(e: any) {
      // console.log(e)
      target.set.call(this, e)
    },
  };

  return result;
}

class GlobalStore {
  constructor() { }

  @State
  accessor username = 'test'

  setUsername(data: string): void {
    this.username = data
  }

  getUsername(): string {
    return this.username
  }
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

you can see here -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-haafpu?file=src%2Fstore.ts
playgorundlink

Do you have experimentalDecorators enabled? https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#experimentalDecorators I can get your same error in the playground when I turn that on: https://tsplay.dev/WKZDom

@AlexWayne I updated post. I added experimentalDecorators

    "experimentalDecorators": true,

This means you are not using the new decorator syntax introduced in Typescript 5.0.
See:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#experimentalDecorators.
There was an old implementation of a standard for decorators that did not make it through the process to become a real javascript feature. Typescript adopted that standard early, and a lot of people used it. Then the standard evolved.
Typescript 5.0 introduced a new decorator syntax that is closer to what Javascript is/will be natively supporting.
Enabling experimentalDecorators opts you into the older decorator syntax. But you are writing decorators in the new syntax.

thank you response. @AlexWayne I am using tsyringe this package. now giving error this package.

If you want to use the new decorator syntax, then you can't depend on a project that requires the legacy experimental decorators. They are mutually exclusive. Either write your decorators the legacy way or don't use tsyringe. That's just how it is.
